# PySide widget invoke Windows 8.1 Virtual Keyboard

Tags: qt, keyboard, windows-8.1, pyside

I've written a desktop application in PySide, which works as required. The scope of the project has changed, such that the application will now be run on Windows 8.1 touchscreens, thus requiring the use of a virtual/on-screen keyboard.

I've written and implemented my own PySide keyboard in the past, but would like to utilise the Windows 8.1 virtual keyboard if possible. I've amended my code to set the various QWidget, TextEdits, etc. to accept touch events (Qt.WA_AcceptTouchEvents), but this is NOT invoking the Windows 8.1 virtual keyboard.

Is there a signal I need to be using to tell Windows to show the virtual keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this doesn't directly help but it should be a good pointer:

PySide.QtGui.QApplication.autoSipEnabled()
Return type:    PySide.QtCore.bool
This property holds toggles automatic SIP (software input panel) visibility.

Set this property to true to automatically display the SIP when entering widgets that accept keyboard input. This property only affects widgets with the WA_InputMethodEnabled attribute set, and is typically used to launch a virtual keyboard on devices which have very few or no keys.

The property only has an effect on platforms which use software input panels, such as Windows CE and Symbian.

The default is platform dependent.

static PySide.QtGui.QApplication.beep()
Sounds the bell, using the default volume and sound. The function is not available in Qt for Embedded Linux.

That is straight from the documentation. I'd imaging that you should be able to turn this on and then it would signal Windows 8 to put up the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Cameron, much appreciated! I'll give this a go shortly and report back.